# Add option to Maven command line in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am dealing with this problem. I have a maven project witch works fine, until i tried add some junit dependencies, so this dependecies are detected but don't downloaded, so i had to download and install manually. Until here netbeans looks fine, but when i run i get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project project: Could not resolve dependencies for project ar.com.project:project:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE (compile), com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.2.2 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11-redhat-1 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3-redhat-1: Failure to find org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:pom:1.3-redhat-1 in http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-ga-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

If you go to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException and read the comment, it looks that gut had my same problem i the solution is to add -U option but i don't find where :s. Do you know where?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to add the option, look the image, yet my problem persist :( so it was not that the problem.

[image]